# Does linearity of cofactor imply linearity of determinant for 3×3 symmetric matrices?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices

$\DeclareMathOperator\cof{cof}$If we suppose that a finite family (greater than 3) of $3\times3$ symmetric matrices $A_i$ and positive reals $a_i$ such that $\sum_ia_i=1$ satisfies
$\cof(\sum_i a_i A_i)=\sum_ia_i\cof A_i$,
does this imply that the same happens for determinant?
Is it true that
$\det(\sum_i a_i A_i)=\sum_ia_i\det A_i$?
If not, what is a counterexample?

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! You can improve the formatting of your post by [edit]ing it to use MathJax; see [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/228959) for a tutorial.

Comment: In fact your post was already mostly TeX'd; you just need to wrap TeX in `$$`.  Note the difference between \sigma_i a_i=1 and $\sigma_i a_i=1$ `$\sigma_i a_i=1$`.  But actually please use `\sum` for sums instead of `\sigma` (or rather `\Sigma`, which is what you probably meant); compare, for example, $\Sigma_i a_i=1$ `\Sigma_i a_i=1` to $\sum_i a_i=1$ `\sum_i a_i=1`, and especially $\displaystyle\Sigma_i a_i=1$ `\displaystyle\Sigma_i a_i=1` to $\displaystyle\sum_i a_i=1$ `\displaystyle\sum_i a_i=1`.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you asking that your matrices $A_i$ $(1\le i\le n)$ be such that for *every* choice of $a_i>0$ with $a_1+\cdots+a_n=1$, we have $\sum_{i=1}^na_i\,\mathrm{cof}(A_i) =\mathrm{cof}\bigl( \sum_{i=1}^n a_i\,A_i\bigr)$, or just that there is *some* such choice of $a_i$?

Comment: I would certainly like to see to see an answer to this question. So, I don't understand the close votes. Is there an obvious answer?

Comment: @RobertBryant: I think the question is this: If $3\times3$ symmetric matrices $A_i$ and positive reals $a_i$ are such that $\sum_ia_i=1$ and $\cof(\sum_i a_i A_i)=\sum_ia_i\cof A_i$,
does it necessarily follow that 
$\det(\sum_i a_i A_i)=\sum_ia_i\det A_i$?

Comment: @IosifPinelis:  I agree that that is the literal question, but it seems kind of odd, since the title of the question asks about a property of 'linearity', which is not really relevant if the $a_i$ are not allowed to be variable.

Comment: @RobertBryant : I see. I did not pay enough attention to the title, which is indeed a bit misleading. However, I find the question interesting and would very much like to see an answer, which is think would be positive!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a counterexample to the OP's literal question:  Consider the following four symmetric (in fact, diagonal) $3$-by-$3$ matrices:  $A_1 = \mathrm{diag}(0,0,0)$, $A_2 = \mathrm{diag}(\frac12,3,3)$, $A_3 = \mathrm{diag}(0,11,1)$, $A_4 = \mathrm{diag}(1,6,0)$, and let $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=\frac14$.  Then the cofactor equation holds, but the determinant equation does not.

Meanwhile, if, instead one asks that the symmetric matrices $A_i$ have the property that the cofactor equation holds for *all* choices of $a_i$ for which $\sum_i a_i = 1$ and $a_i>0$, then, indeed, the determinant equation holds also for all choices of $a_i$ for which $\sum_i a_i = 1$ and $a_i>0$.

To see this, note first that the cofactor function on $3$-by-$3$ matrices $A\mapsto \mathrm{cof}(A)$ is a quadratic function (i.e., the mapping $\beta(A,B) = \mathrm{cof}(A+B) - \mathrm{cof}(A)-\mathrm{cof}(B)$ is (symmetric and) bilinear in its arguments. In particular, it is homogeneous of degre $2$.

Almost by definition, $\mathrm{cof}(A)=0$ if and only if $A$ has rank at most $1$, i.e. $A = pq^\mathsf{T}$ for some column vectors $p$ and $q$.  In particular, when $A$ is also symmetric, it must be a multiple of $pp^\mathsf{T}$ for some column vector $p$.

Now, suppose that one has $3$-by-$3$ matrices $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ such that $\mathrm{cof}(a_1\,A_1 + \cdots + a_n\,A_n) = a_1\,\mathrm{cof}(A_1)+\cdots+a_n\,\mathrm{cof}(A_n)$ for all $a_i>0$ with $a_1+\cdots+a_n=1$. Writing $a_i = b_i/(b_1+\cdots+b_n)$ for $b_i>0$, substituting and clearing denominators, one sees that
$$
\mathrm{cof}(b_1\,A_1 {+} \cdots {+} b_n\,A_n) = (b_1{+}\cdots{+}b_n)\bigl(b_1\,\mathrm{cof}(A_1)+\cdots+b_n\,\mathrm{cof}(A_n)\bigr)
$$
for all $b_i>0$.  Since both sides of this equation are quadratic polynomials in the $b_i$, it follows that this equation must hold for *all* $b_i$, not just when the $b_i$ are positive.  In particular, we must have
$$
\mathrm{cof}(b_1\,A_1 {+} \cdots {+} b_n\,A_n)=0
$$
when $b_1+\cdots+b_n=0$.  In particular, $\mathrm{cof}(A_i-A_j) = 0$ for all $i$ and $j$, so that $A_i-A_j$ has rank at most $1$.  Moreover,
$$
\mathrm{cof}\bigl((A_i{-}A_j)- (A_k{-}A_l)\bigr)=0
$$
for all $i$, $j$, $k$ and $l$.  It follows easily that there must be a column vector $p$ and constants $c_i$ such that $A_i = A_0 + c_i\,pp^\mathsf{T}$, where $A_0$ is the average of the $A_i$ for $1\le i\le n$ and $c_1+\cdots+c_n=0$.  Conversely, for $A_i$ of this form, we have
$$
\mathrm{cof}(A_i) = \mathrm{cof}(A_0) + c_i\,\beta(A_0,pp^\mathsf{T}),
$$
and the equation
$$
\mathrm{cof}(a_1\,A_1 + \cdots + a_n\,A_n) = a_1\,\mathrm{cof}(A_1)+\cdots+a_n\,\mathrm{cof}(A_n)
$$
for $a_1+\cdots+a_n=1$ follows immediately from these formulae.  Moreover, one now easily checks that
$$
\det(A_i) = \det(A_0) + c_i\gamma(A_0,A_0,pp^\mathsf{T})
$$
where $\gamma$ is a certain trilinear function on matrices, and the desired determinant identity
$$
\mathrm{det}(a_1\,A_1 + \cdots + a_n\,A_n) = a_1\,\mathrm{det}(A_1)+\cdots+a_n\,\mathrm{det}(A_n)
$$
for $a_1+\cdots+a_n=1$ follows immediately from these formulae.

Comment: Thank you very much, in fact your counter example is well performed. Thanks again!

Comment: @Yacine:  If you are satisfied wiith my answer, then you should probably accept it so that it will not keep coming up on the front page.  If you are not satisfied, then you should let me know what kind of information would improve the answer.  Personally, I think that just the counterexample alone is not as interesting as the positive answer to the more restrictive question.